# Computing $\lim_{d\to \infty} \frac{1}{d}\frac{\sum_{i,j=1,1}^d\left(i^{-p}-j^{-p}\right)^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^d i^{-p}\right)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I compute the following for $p\ge 1$?

$$f(p)=\lim_{d\to \infty} \frac{1}{d}\frac{\sum_{i,j=1,1}^d\left(i^{-p}-j^{-p}\right)^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^d i^{-p}\right)^2}$$

Upon numerical [approximation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-variance-sums.nb), I observed:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 f(1)=& 0 \\
 f(2)\stackrel{?}{=} & \frac{4}{5} \\
\end{array}
$$

I managed to work out $f(1)$ case by using result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4183090/998), but unsure how to extend this to other values of $p$.

The motivation is to compute the limiting variance of $f(\mathbf{x})=x_1/1^p + x_2/2^p + x_3/3^p+\ldots$ with $\mathbf{x}$ a random point on a sphere of a fixed radius such that $E[f(\mathbf{x})]=1$, using variance formula derived [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532117/distribution-of-langle-x2-a-rangle-where-x-is-is-a-random-direction/532222#532222)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^d(i^{-p}-j^{-p})^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^d(i^{-2p}+j^{-2p}-2i^{-p}j^{-p})=2d\sum_{i=1}^p i^{-2p}-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^d i^{-p}\right)^2$$ gives $\color{blue}{f(p)=2\zeta(2p)/\zeta^2(p)}$ for $p>1$; $f(2)=\frac45$ is confirmed by $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6$ and $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$.

Comment: Thanks, also confirmed using cas [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286120/plotting-frac1d-frac-sum-ijdi-p-j-p2-left-sum-id-i-p-r#comment712470_286135)