# Asymptotic behavior of $\frac{1}{d}\sum_{ij=(1,1)}^d \left(f(i,s)-f(j,s)\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is there a nice expression for $V(s)$ defined below for $1<p\le 2$ and large $d$?

$$V(s)=\frac{1}{d}\sum_{ij=(1,1)}^d \left(f(i,s)-f(j,s)\right)^2$$
$$f(i,s)=i^{-p}(1-i^{-p})^s$$

Empirically it [appears](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-variance-over-time.nb) to settle into log-linear growth after initial transient period

[image]

Motivation: this gives variance of gradient descent estimate with random starting point after $s/2$ steps. $s=2$ case was solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713352/computing-lim-d-to-infty-frac1d-frac-sum-i-j-1-1d-lefti-p-j)